# dowload libclang-3.5-dev linux 12.04

Tags: 12.04, downloads, c++, libraries

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to download libclang-3.5-dev. 
I can't upgrade my version because some projects don't run in another newer version. 
Could you help me how to download libclang-3.5-dev??

Comment: 12.04 is end of life and no longer supported here.

Comment: take a look at this ppa, you may or may not need 12.04's repos active or if they're not switch to the old-release repos . https://launchpad.net/~pali/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers